# Help to show the next proposition

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow R$ be a bounded function in $[a,b]$ such that $f$ is equal to zero except for a finite number of points in $[a,b]$. Show that $f$ is integrable and that its integral is zero.

I attempted the solution by induction over the number of points in which $f \neq 0$. Starting with only one point, and getting that it works for n number of points.

Proof: By induction.

Base case: Suppose that $f(x) = 0\; \forall x \neq c$ with c being a point in $[a,b]$.

But I don't know how to continue with the proof.

Comment: Are we talking about Riemann integration or Lebesgue integration?  (Note, by the way, that if the function is nonzero at all but finitely many points, it's necessarily bounded so you won't need to separately use the condition that it's bounded.)

Comment: We are talking about Riemann integration. Ok, so I don't have to use the fact that it is bounded

Answer (score 1):

Let $a < x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n < b$ be the $n$ distinct points where $f \ne 0$. (Although $a = x_1$ and $x_n = b$ are possible, just take $\hat{a} < a$ and $\hat{b} > b$ and consider the same problem on $[\hat{a}, \hat{b}]$.) Without loss of generality, assume $f \geq 0$. Let $C = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)$.

We need to show that $L(f) = U(f)$, where $L(f) = \sup_P L(f,P)$ and $U(f) = \inf_P U(f,P)$.

First, let's show that $L(f) = 0$. To this end, let $P = \{a = y_0 < y_1 < \dots < y_m = b \}$ be any partition of $[a,b]$. Then $\inf\{f(x) : y_i \leq x \leq y_{i+1}\} = 0$ for each $i$, so $L(f,P) = 0$; hence, $L(f) =0$.

Conversely, let $\varepsilon > 0$ be sufficiently small. Consider the partition
$$
P_\varepsilon = \{ x_i \pm \varepsilon : i = 1, \dots, n \}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
  U(f, P_\varepsilon) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sup\{f(x) : |x-x_i| \leq \varepsilon \} \cdot 2\varepsilon \\ 
  &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2\varepsilon f(x_i) \\
  &= 2 C \varepsilon,
\end{align}
so $U(f) = \inf_P U(f,P) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} U(f,P_\varepsilon) = 0$.

Since $U(f) = L(f)$, it follows that $f$ is Riemann integrable. Moreover, $\int_a^b f = 0$.

Comment: To simplify the proof and present it in a manner a little more aligned with Gabriel's original thinking, you can first do the proof assuming there's only one non-zero point, and then partition the interval of integration so that each side of your partition has at least one non-zero point and proceed by induction.